# Maximum call stack size exceeded 5

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
 $("#submit_bill").on('click', function() {
   $.post(url, {
     note: note,
     products: products,
     quantity: quantity,
     pro_txt: pro_txt,
     payment_method: payment_method,
     client_id: $('#client_id').val(),
     type: $_billType,
     id_account: $('#com_id').val(),
     id_branch: $('#branch_id').val(),
     total: final_total,
     total_before_discount: total_before_discount,
     discount: discount,
     discount_type: "rs",
     tree_id: tree_id,
     user_id: $(this).find('#user_id').val(),
     bill: 'bill',
     bill_type: 'touch',
     value: value,
     add_bond: add_bond,
     payment: payment,
     print: 1,
     pay_way: 0,
     room_id: $('#room_id').val(),
     related_bill_id: $('#related_bill_id').val(),
     DetailedPay: DetailedPay,
     options: options
   }, function(donee) {
     bill_id = donee;
     $(".modal").modal("hide");
     url = '<?=ADMIN_ROOT?>/bills/show_bill&ajax&touch&print&id=' + bill_id;
     $('#print_div').html('<iframe src="' + url + '" id="print_frame"></iframe>');
     $.post('<?=ADMIN_ROOT?>/bills/printCount&ajax', {
       id: bill_id
     }, function() {
       location.reload()
     });
   }, 'JSON');
 });
```

I am getting this JavaScript error in Chrome:
When click submit, this error (Maximum call stack size exceeded) appears,
what to solve this problem?

Comment: So, `submit` leads to `post`, which (if successful) leads to `post`, which leads to `reload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit.

This is almost always because of a recursive function with a base case that isn't being met.

Consider this code...

```
(function a() {
    a();
})();
```

Comment: This is a good explanation, but not an actual answer. It should really be a comment.

Comment: @MohamedElzainy Wherever you want that error to occur

Comment: @ScottMarcus The user is too new to leave comments yet, and I think this is about as helpful as it gets since the OP seems to have not posted the code that causes the infinite recursion. You are right though, if the user had enough rep to leave comments I wouldn't have upvoted this.

Comment: @Paulpro The user could have edited the question and posted an UPDATE section to it. This shouldn't be upvoted.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The OP can still do that

Comment: I know, yet he hasn't.